# Track certain movements in WatchKit app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

Is it possible to track certain movements of the user in my WatchKit app? For example, I'd like my app to track how many somersaults you do in a week. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with the current version of the WatchKit SDK. Developers don't have access to any of the device's sensors.

Comment: hello, 
is that possible now?
I face the same problem and I didn't find any useful tutorial on it